# Abolsute paths not working on <img> src

Tags: html, image

I am reading a JPG file from a local directory and when I render the web page, it does not show the image.

I do not want to move this image in the project directory. I want to keep it as-is in the local directory.

This is what I have:

```
<img src="file://C:/dir1/dir2/filename.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="500" height="400"/>
```

I'm using IE to display the web page. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute path is from your **root web directory**, not your file directory:

```
<img src="/images/filename.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="500" height="400"/>
```

If that file is not inside your root web directory or a subdirectory thereof you won't be able to view it in your HTML (without the help of server side code).

Answer (score 1):

You might still get away with images. But as far as I know, you cannot load files from local disk. This would be a massive security breach as a webpage could load anything it wanted from your hard drive.

You will need a small webserver to load external assets...

[here](http://phaser.io/getting-started-js.php) is a great explanation why...

Answer (score 0):

You still can do something like that, but you will need server side code that would evaluate the request and serve the content of the file to the client with the appropriate MIME type. The file:/// URIs always refer to the client local file system, so the server would not even receive such a request.